# Unexpected syntax error after loading reticulate package

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I've loaded "reticulate" package to run python code in Rstudio.
Below the code:

```py
# Initialize an empty dictionary
D = {} 

L = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['a', 3], ['c', 4]]
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected '[[' in "L = [["
```

Why did this happen?

No answers on Google helped me.

Comment: What you've shown in your question is **valid** Python. If *reticulate* (whatever that is) thinks it's wrong then maybe someone interested in *reticulate* can help. It's not a Python issue

Comment: That's not a Python error message. I don't know anything about the other tools you mentioned though.

Comment: Probably RStudio is running this is as if it were R code, not Python. Does your file have a `.py` extension?

Comment: Or, more broadly: are you using one of the methods described here to run Python code? https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/

Comment: As slothrop suggested, basically I hadn't saved file with .py extension.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try

```
py_run_string("L = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['a', 3], ['c', 4]]")
```

such that

```
> L
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "b"

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 2


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
[1] "a"

[[3]][[2]]
[1] 3


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
[1] "c"

[[4]][[2]]
[1] 4
```